# slider revolution how can I hide layer when playing video

Tags: video, slider-revolution

How can I hide some layers when I click in the action
for example I have a video that have a play button how can I remove it when I click the video?

Comment: Are you using Javascript??? If yes, find out the ID of the item or layer then use JS to set its CSS setting of `visibility` to "hidden"... _eg:_ `myPlayBtn.style.visibility = "hidden";`